# ngMessages with Angular 1.5.x Component

Tags: angularjs

I just tried introducing ngMessages into my app that's using Components that were added in 1.5. As soon as I include any reference to ngMessage in my template I'm receiving this error message:

> Error: $compile:ctreq Missing Required Controller.
>
> This is a common error with ngMessages and the normal remedy is
>   suggested here:
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngMessages&p1=ngMessage

However, I'm using components, which are a special type of directive and this doesn't appear to be an option for components.

Has anyone gotten **ngMessages** to work within a **component** in 1.5?

The syntax for use with a directive is like this:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    ...
  }
}
```

The component documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component doesn't cover an equivalent to `require`.

Comment: Why the down vote with no explanation?

Comment: Upvoted :) When I check the comparaison between directive & component, it looks like they both accept the require configuration https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#comparison-between-directive-definition-and-component-definition

Comment: See my comment on the accepted answer. It appears that require is not necessary. (I actually tried it.) The problem was my ommission of the outer ng-messages div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.

```
<form name="userLoginForm" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" required ng-model="userData.mobileNumber" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" class="form-control login-form-input" id="mobileNumber" name="mobileNumberInput"/> 
    <div ng-messages="userLoginForm.mobileNumberInput.$error" role="alert">
      <div ng-message="required">
          This field is required
      </div>
      <div  ng-message="pattern">
        Enter correct mobile number
      </div>
      <div ng-message="minlength, maxlength">
          Your mobile number must 10 characters long</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: It turns out that this was actually helpful. I was missing the outer div and that's actually what causes the error. The error message and documentation are very misleading.

Comment: It's funny how the OP complains about a down vote on the question w/out explanation, but when this answer helped the OP they couldn't be bothered to up vote it.

Comment: Actually, I originally down voted it and do to some time constraint I was not allowed to change the down vote. That's why I added the comment immediately above yours and accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you don't have correct div structure.
First div has to include ng-messages, and one inside should be ng-message.
From Documentation:

```
<ANY **ng-messages**="expression" role="alert">
    <ANY **ng-message**="stringValue">...</ANY>
</ANY>
```

Angular's debug message is unhelpful in this instance and cause more confusion.